# Incorrect inclusion value - SOAP Request

Tags: web-services, websphere-liberty

Using Liberty 19.0.09, I have this Exception "Incorrect inclusion value".

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Incorrect inclusion value: null.
Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException - Incorrect inclusion value: null
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.model.Token.setInclusion(Token.java:82)

I have tried multiple configurations without success. Here is the code I am using to access this WS :

```
>DocumentMgmtHttpService service = new DocumentMgmtHttpService();
>HandlerResolver resolver = service.getHandlerResolver();           
>DocumentMgmt docmgmt = service.getDocumentMgmtHttpPort();      

>BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) docmgmt;        
>bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "xxxx");
>bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "xxxxx");        
>SearchDocumentResponseType response=null;
```

then the request and the call

*Where should I be looking ?*

I have configure ( 3 features below ) + handlers + CallBackHandler ( as a feature on the server )

- **server.xml**

> ```
> <wsSecurityClient id="default" 
> ws-security.callback-handler="com.xxx.xxxx.callbackhandler.CallBackHandler"
> ws-security.signature.username="portal_certificate"
> ws-security.username="CN=portalx509.xxxxxxxxxx, OU=IT, O=xxxxxxxxx, L=xxxxxxxx, ST=xxxxx, C=CA"       
> ws-security.encryption.username="portal_certificate">
>   <signatureProperties
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type="jceks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias="portal_certificate"            
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/keystore-ti.jks"
>           org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.file="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/keystore-ti.jks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.type="jceks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="/>
>
>   <encryptionProperties
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type="jceks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias="portal_certificate"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/keystore-ti.jks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.type="jceks"
>           org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.file="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/keystore-ti.jks"
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="            
>       org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password="{xor}PDc+MTg6Nis="
> ```
>
> />

```
 - **ibm-ws-bnd.xml**
```

> ```
> <ws:webservices-bnd   xmlns:ws="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ws-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
>     <ws:webservice-endpoint-properties enableLoggingInOutInterceptor="true" />
>     <ws:service-ref name="service/DocumentMgmtHttpService">
>         <ws:port name="DocumentMgmtHttpPort" namespace="http://ibm.com/ws/jaxws/transport/security/" ssl-ref="SSL01" /> 
>     <ws:properties http.conduit.tlsClientParameters.disableCNCheck="true" />
> </ws:service-ref>     
> </ws:webservices-bnd>
> ```

- **policy-attachements-client.xml ( in WEB-INF )**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attachments
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:sp13="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200802"
    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
    <wsp:PolicyAttachment
        wsdlNamespace="http://www.xxxxx.xx/EnterpriseMgmt/DocumentMgmt/V1">
        <wsp:AppliesTo>
            <wsa:EndpointReference>             
                <wsa:Address>https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8442/ti/DocumentMgmt/V1
                </wsa:Address>
            </wsa:EndpointReference>
            <wsp:URI>https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8442/ti/DocumentMgmt/V1#wsdl11.service(DocumentMgmtHttpService)</wsp:URI>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wsp:Policy
            wsu:Id="X509AsymmetricMutualAndUntAuthentication">
            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                <wsp:All>
                    <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="true">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                                <wsp:All />
                                <wsam:AnonymousResponses />
                                <wsam:NonAnonymousResponses />
                            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </wsam:Addressing>
                    <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens
                        xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:UsernameToken
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssUsernameToken11 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:UsernameToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                    <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:InitiatorToken>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:X509Token
                                        sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200712/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                        <wsp:Policy>
                                            <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                                        </wsp:Policy>
                                    </sp:X509Token>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:InitiatorToken>
                            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Basic128Rsa15 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <sp:RecipientToken>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:X509Token
                                        sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200712/IncludeToken/AlwaysToInitiator">
                                        <wsp:Policy>
                                            <sp:WssX509V3Token11 />
                                        </wsp:Policy>
                                    </sp:X509Token>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:RecipientToken>
                            <sp:Layout>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Strict />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:Layout>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                    <sp:SupportingTokens>
                        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="request:username_token">
                            <sp:UsernameToken
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200712/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssUsernameToken11 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:UsernameToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:SupportingTokens>
                    <sp:SignedParts>
                        <sp:Body />
                        <sp:Header
                            Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" />
                        <sp:Header
                            Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                        <sp:Header
                            Namespace="http://www.nbfg.ca/fw/serviceHeaders" />
                    </sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:SignedElements>
                        <sp:XPath>/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Envelope']/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Header']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Security']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Timestamp']</sp:XPath>
                        <sp:XPath>/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' and local-name()='Envelope']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' and local-name()='Header']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Security']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='UsernameToken']</sp:XPath>
                        <sp:XPath>/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' and local-name()='Envelope']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' and local-name()='Header']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Security']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Timestamp']</sp:XPath>
                        <sp:XPath>/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Envelope']/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' and local-name()='Header']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='Security']/*[namespace-uri()='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' and local-name()='UsernameToken']</sp:XPath>
                    </sp:SignedElements>
                </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </wsp:PolicyAttachment>
</attachments>
```

Any help ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your policy-attachments-client.xml, the IncludeToken value is not correct. Update all the IncludeToken values and change "200712" to "200702".